# How can I disable "Use automatic checkpoints" for new Hyper-V VM's on Windows 10?

Tags: hyper-v

On Windows 10, when a new VM is created, it has "Use automatic checkpoints" in Settings/Checkpoints turned on by default. If I recall correctly, this was a change that the Windows team made some months ago on Windows 10 Insider builds (it doesn't happen on Server).

Is there a way in the registry or through PowerShell or somewhere else to turn that off so it doesn't happen to my new VM's on Windows 10?

[image: Hyper-V Checkpoint settings]

Comment: Also you can accept your own self-answered question in some days.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From a helpful fellow commenting at http://web.archive.org/web/20170509161254/https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/virtualization/2017/04/20/making-it-easier-to-revert/:

```
Set-VM -Name MyVM -AutomaticCheckpointsEnabled $false
```

will tell **Hyper-V on Windows 10** not to use automatic checkpoints **for that virtual machine only**. I'm still not aware of a way to tell the Windows 10 Hyper-V host not to set that option on new VM's, but at least we have a good workaround.

Note: As of August 2017, automatic checkpoints are used only on Windows 10 and not on Windows Server 2016, so this parameter doesn't exist on Windows Server 2016.

Comment: I have no idea why this question was closed as off-topic. Apparently the administrators here feel that Windows 10 and Hyper-V don't exist in business environments, or that I'm automating the deployment of VM's as a fun hobby at home. Sigh.

Comment: no idea too... but as in some of my questions the same happened... and even worse when I reply to the guy who closed the question sometimes my comments are deleted... after a few times I just gave up,,,

Comment: @Scott, very helpful, thanks. Shame the question was closed for such a trivial reason.

Comment: This question is relevant to those who deploy and manage tens of thousands of endpoint computers in the enterprise, using servers no less. On-topic.